# label bar chart in Vega Lite with both absolute number and percentage

Tags: vega-lite

I am able to label a bar chart created in Vega Lite, with either its percentage of the total or its absolute number, like so:

[image]

And here's the spec:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "width": "container",
  "height": "container",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "binMin": -300,
        "binMax": 0,
        "binName": "-5 to 0 minutes",
        "count": 29,
        "percentOfTotal": 0.14215686274509803
      },
      {
        "binMin": 0,
        "binMax": 360,
        "binName": "0 to +6 minutes",
        "count": 51,
        "percentOfTotal": 0.25
      },
      {
        "binMin": 360,
        "binMax": 600,
        "binName": "+6 to +10 minutes",
        "count": 32,
        "percentOfTotal": 0.1568627450980392
      },
      {
        "binMin": 600,
        "binMax": 1200,
        "binName": "+10 to +20 minutes",
        "count": 90,
        "percentOfTotal": 0.4411764705882353
      }
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": "bar"},
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "center",
        "yOffset": -10,
        "fontSize": 18
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "percentOfTotal",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "format": ".0%",
          "formatType": "number"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "binName",
      "type": "nominal",
      "title": "Wait Time for Transfer (Minutes)",
      "axis": {"titleFontSize": 18, "labelAngle": 0, "labelFontSize": 14},
      "sort": {"field": "binMin"}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "count",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "Total Transfers",
      "axis": {"titleFontSize": 18, "labelFontSize": 14}
    },
    "color": {
      "legend": false,
      "field": "binMin",
      "scale": {"range": ["red", "orange", "green", "yellowgreen"]}
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to change the label to display both, like a label for the left/red bar of "29 (14%)".

I have figured out how to set `config.customFormatTypes = true` and to write a little formatter function in JavaScript. However, I am unclear how I would be able to pass two fields into this formatter, in order to pass it both the absolute number and the percentage (or the absolute number for that category and the total number across all categories).

Any pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the concatenated value of 2 fields `"29 (14%)"` over text you can use transform `calculate` and generate a concatenated string based on your field. Then, use that field in your `text` mark as done below or refer [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemhBQ5mJDVlwATooxwaZLFp2y9B46bVI9aUMSSCGcCGgDaoJgMAWQM0fgBmAAZIpUDZIKQADzQYkDiAOSQEOC1+AFYAAkw2AsiChAMGTG9THQZbNAAmAE4lHGMoOFsAeQAzABU2PUEUygBGMUaxvIA2AA4ZxoB2MTzI5rnI8IBfBQDg0NRUuITk1HCZ44NM7K0y4oKAahnyyuqfJTqG1Dyxto6upg+oNhqNGnldvt4ocLld4kk0Jc4TccuhnkUSo8xmUKrIqjVPmx6pg0OFGv8jJ0egMhh5RtN5osVmsNltmo1IWkDvJUEjYsEEagxo1ovzZCitFj7piRa88e9akTvs1Uu1KYDgbSRkdKGIxGMxksZmIlpE8nM5o1wnkdgBdXYgQRIACeDlQ-hAyCMAGstEwkCZOZgjEhZBBemwjAg-KAoB4oAwndUtBGo84ABROTAMBCUNVUoE04YKAoAckokQApKWAJSmJA+dD5gD6xVBnLjggTSdRICzOcoX0wj1LBXTo8e-dzLbbHietdL9cb2iVmAACgDbP04IkSdtbUovb7UKBMM72lpqrv68IyDztICHEpnX1ehA4CTUPxsUoI7YAMo0AAXqiYxzA6XQ6GoBhkK4IBXp+oC9DQcCCGo1irhu6pbjuJJKGeF7oJG0GyHS2zkQeICQWwJGwSeIBnEhKFoX61xZDk+Hnr2shsLidL4XQgi9gA6vomAFP0NDZAUqYSSGYa9MYY4hPK3h1koSQ0I2p6CXAABiuiASBaBgUoTpMKhACCshkEJKRmUgFmCAZAHAaBYgOjIRiISAyGoeh6AnKE5HPnBfksegQ6mARvYAI4MKGmB0M4NCkNFulaCCc79PJ4bGB8ICadp8G6S5mBGaBcwOU5ZUVSZHkOjogiRnBQlkF0AW9B476-sxAVctC8hKNAHioqA8ntX4IBGHA6FKJGoaTUoZAzV0piuoIzXKCtcBrfa5HbEAA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "width": "container",
  "height": "container",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "binMin": -300,
        "binMax": 0,
        "binName": "-5 to 0 minutes",
        "count": 29,
        "percentOfTotal": 0.14215686274509803
      },
      {
        "binMin": 0,
        "binMax": 360,
        "binName": "0 to +6 minutes",
        "count": 51,
        "percentOfTotal": 0.25
      },
      {
        "binMin": 360,
        "binMax": 600,
        "binName": "+6 to +10 minutes",
        "count": 32,
        "percentOfTotal": 0.1568627450980392
      },
      {
        "binMin": 600,
        "binMax": 1200,
        "binName": "+10 to +20 minutes",
        "count": 90,
        "percentOfTotal": 0.4411764705882353
      }
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": "bar"},
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "calculate": "format(datum.percentOfTotal, '.0%')",
          "as": "perc_total"
        },
        {
          "calculate": "datum.count+' (' +datum.perc_total +')'",
          "as": "countPercentText"
        }
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "center",
        "yOffset": -10,
        "fontSize": 18
      },
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "countPercentText", "type": "ordinal"}}
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "binName",
      "type": "nominal",
      "title": "Wait Time for Transfer (Minutes)",
      "axis": {"titleFontSize": 18, "labelAngle": 0, "labelFontSize": 14},
      "sort": {"field": "binMin"}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "count",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "Total Transfers",
      "axis": {"titleFontSize": 18, "labelFontSize": 14}
    },
    "color": {
      "legend": false,
      "field": "binMin",
      "scale": {"range": ["red", "orange", "green", "yellowgreen"]}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!